# What purpose of the Spring @EnableAsync annotation, and how to use it well?

Tags: spring

I have read The doc of this annotation and i couldn't understand it ! Can someone offer some
explanation. Any hints will be appreciated!

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html) describe the use of this annotation quite precisely. What exactly do you **not** understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @EnableAsync annotation switches on Spring’s ability to run @Async methods in a background thread pool. This class also customizes the used Executor by defining a new bean. 
Please check the example https://dzone.com/articles/spring-and-threads-async

So it will enable thread pool which will be looking for methods annotated "@Async" and run them.

Very clear example: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-creating-asynchronous-methods-using-as

Comment: Thank you Romas! That is very helpful to me ! Have a nice day~