# Why need @EnableAsync annotation since @EnableScheduling already trigger scheduled task on a different thread asynchronously?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, concurrency

I have the following code using @EnableScheduling and @EnableAsync together:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class PollingAgent {

    @Async
    @Scheduled(fixedRate=INTERVAL_RATE, initialDelay = 10000) //setting an initial delay to let the beans get loaded
    void checkAvailableAndStartJob() {
        if(m_messageOnDemand) {
            try {
                LOGGER.info("check job messages and start job if possible");
                jobIdOnDemandSubscriber.StartJobIfMessageAvailable(m_applicationContext);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.info("Scheduler run failed: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think even without `@EnableAsync` and `@Async`, `checkAvailableAndStartJob` will be triggered asynchronously on a different thread, why we need them?

Comment: Maybe this post can help you too.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801769/what-purpose-of-the-spring-enableasync-annotation-and-how-to-use-it-well

Comment: Thanks! but if I only use `@EnableScheduling` without `@EnableAsync`, how can the scheduled task run? (I suppose the scheduled task should run on a separate thread asyncrously)

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623092/using-spring-scheduled-and-async-together

Answer (score 1):

I do not think @Async and @Scheduled are meant to be used on the same method, even if it does work.

- First, a @Scheduled method should return void and have no parameters (for obvious reasons), whereas an @Async method can have parameters and can return a value (i.e. `Future<?>`).
- Second, @EnableScheduling will look for a `TaskScheduler` to execute the @Scheduled methods, whereas @EnableAsync will look for a `TaskExecutor` to execute the @Async methods. The two are different things, Spring doc [says](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#scheduling):

  > The Spring Framework provides abstractions for the **asynchronous execution** and **scheduling** of tasks with the **TaskExecutor** and **TaskScheduler** interfaces, *respectively*.

---

However, it is possible to use @EnableAsync and @EnableScheduling on the same @Configuration class, depending on what you want to do. For example, the Spring documentation [shows](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#scheduling-enable-annotation-support) this example:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {}
```

It can indeed be a bit confusing at first, but as they mention:

> You can pick and choose the relevant annotations for your application. For example, if you need only support for @Scheduled, you can omit @EnableAsync.

The example is probably there if you want to do something like:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {

    @Async // requires @EnableAsync
    public Future<String> asyncMethod(String data) {
        // do something
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("finished");
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1_000) // requires @EnableScheduling
    public void everySecond() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

---

As for your question, *how can the scheduled task run?*, the doc for [@EnableScheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html) says:

> By default, Spring will search for an associated scheduler definition: either a unique TaskScheduler bean in the context, or a TaskScheduler bean named "taskScheduler" otherwise; (…). If neither of the two is resolvable, a **local single-threaded default scheduler** will be created and used within the registrar.

So, if you have multiple @Scheduled methods and want them to be able to execute in parallel, you need to define a `TaskScheduler` with a pool size greater than one:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerContext {

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("sched-task-");
        scheduler.setPoolSize(10); // 1 is the default value
        scheduler.initialize();
        return scheduler;
    }
}
```